# How do you change the src of an image tag if a button tag is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I were to create an image and give it the source of "box.png", using CSS or Javascript, how could I make a button change the source of the image to "package.png"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the button changes the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element in the event listener.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
let logo = document.getElementById('logo');

let darkImageURL = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/196/196685.png";
let lightImageURL = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/169/169367.png";

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(this.innerHTML === "Dark") {
    document.body.style.background = "black";
    this.innerHTML = "Light";
    logo.src = darkImageURL;
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    this.innerHTML = "Dark";
    logo.src = lightImageURL;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="toggleButton">Dark</button>

  <img id="logo" class="nav_logo" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/169/169367.png" alt="original logo" width="100" height="100"/>
</body>
```